# How to save or read files inside of a simulation

Tags: r, loops, simulation

I am trying to run a simulation. There are certain files that I need to save and sometimes read from inside of the simulation. I have three sample size conditions and I am giving names based on the sample sizes.

For example, the file name is "*binAll.100.dne*" and this is for sample size 100.

Do you have any thoughts on how to save or read this sort files based on differing simulation conditions? Here is my shellcode. I am trying to save an object "*binAll*" as "*binAll.100.dne*" and *N* is my sample size, which is 100 here.

```
start.time = proc.time()

Ns = c(100, 400, 900) # sample sizes
Iterations = 300 #number of iterations/datasets

for (N in Ns){

  #store the results in an empty vector
  all.results <- c() 

  for (iter in 1:Iterations){
  # ALL FUNCTIONS GO HERE
WriteNetworks(binAll,"binAll.100.dne") # how to save this seperately for each sample size      

  } #close dataset loop

  # save the results outside of the dataset loop
  write.table(all.results, file="simulation_results.csv", sep=",", append=T,col.names=F,row.names=F,quote=F) 

  } #close the sample size loop

end.time = proc.time()
total.time = end.time - start.time
```

Thanks for taking your time.
Cheers.

Comment: What exactly is the problem to solve? "how to save or read files based on ... conditions" is very vague... Please edit your questions. THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to base filenames on the sample sizes. You could do this by using the paste() method to concatenate the filename and sample size. See the example below. If this is not what you are after please update your question.

```
N <- 100 # Set sample size

# Create filename
fileName <- paste("binAll", N, "dne", sep=".") 
print(fileName) 

# Example write function
write.table(yourData, file=fileName)
```

Comment: This seems a quick fix. Thanks!